# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda

I'm trying to perform the following

```
int myObject = getValues(someVar).Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Price))
```

The function looks this:

```
List<dynamic> getValues(string something) {...}
```

This is the error I'm receiving:
"Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation"

How can I SUM the values of a List object in a chained call similar to LINQ SUM?

Comment: Note that your problem isn't about lists. You have that problem because you're working with a list of `dynamic`.

Comment: Are there any ways to sum a dynamic list in a chained call similar LINQ SUM?

Comment: This fiddle is not working, but if you copy paste the same in IDE, it works just fine for me. `https://dotnetfiddle.net/O22wlB`

Comment: can you provide `getValues`?

Comment: answered below but I can't accept my own answer yet

Answer (score 4):

Your code works.  The problem you are having isn't in the code you posted.  This code runs.

```
void Main() {
    int myObject = getValues("12").Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Price));
    Console.WriteLine (myObject);
}

List<dynamic> getValues(string something) {
    var item = new { Price = something };
    IEnumerable<dynamic> items = Enumerable.Repeat<dynamic>(item, 2);
    return items.ToList();
}
```

This produces the output `24`.  The problem may be related to type inference, but that's just a guess.  You should include enough code to reproduce the error for a more reliable answer.

Comment: odd my code is setup almost identically but I get an error " "CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type". This is a webforms project / .net 4.5

Comment: They only lambda expression in an argument in your posted code is the call to `.Sum()`.  But I don't think that's dynamically dispatched.  In order for anyone to help you, you'll need to provide enough information to reproduce the problem.  Take your code out of it's context in your application, and reduce it to the minimum required to create the error.  As it is, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, this code is working fine for me:-

```
public static void Main()
{
     var result = GetData("test").Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Name));
     Console.WriteLine(result);
}

    public static List<dynamic> GetData(string x)
     {
         List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>
         {
             new { Id =1, Name ="1"},
             new { Id =2, Name ="4"},
             new { Id =3, Name ="5"}
         };
         return data;
     }
```

I am getting `10` as output.

Comment: odd my code is setup almost identically but I get an error " "CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type". This is a webforms project / .net 4.5

Comment: and please don't spam comments like that - you can always edit your question

Comment: @Rahul Singh, I guess this code's [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O22wlB) throws an exception because - as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7104323/3002584) - anonymous types are created as `internal` by the compiler, so probably some DotNetFiddle assembly can't access them. If one would like to nevertheless use this fiddle, he would have to use some really ugly Reflection tricks (I added some other usages): [https://dotnetfiddle.net/CX0HtS](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CX0HtS).

Answer (score 1):

so it ultimately turned out the issue was that I was passing a dynamic variable into the function call and subsequently using LINQ/lambda. Seems like that's a compiler no-no...

```
dynamic someVar = new {a=1,b=2};

int myObject = getValues(someVar.a).Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Price))
```

Comment: If you replace `var someVar` with `dynamic someVar`, then this would make sense as an explanation.  As it stands though, `var` wouldn't be enough to explain the compiler error.

Comment: but still this don't seem to be an answer - why not just add it to your question instead?

Comment: My honest advice to you is: 1. don't use dynamic - C# has a good enough type-system that you should rarely need it (surely not in this case). 2. Use the debugger 3. read the FAQ/Help around here on how to ask questions

Answer (score 0):

Your `getValues` method is returning a `dynamic`, not a `List<dynamic>`. Either change your method signature or construct a `new List<dynamic>(...)` from its results.

```
dynamic list = new [] {new{Price = "1"},new{Price = "2"}};

// This produces the error you're describing:
Console.WriteLine(list.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Price)));

// This works.
Console.WriteLine(new List<dynamic>(list).Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.Price)));
```

Comment: But return type looks List<dynamic> to me:- `List<dynamic> getValues`

Comment: @RahulSingh: Yes, in the OP it appears that way, but you're assuming that the OP correctly posted his code as-is. I'm reading between the lines, and I'm pretty sure I'm right on this one.

Comment: I am not the OP :D nor I am the down-voter, good analysis though.

Comment: it is return List<dynamic>. oddly i get the error "CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: @user1234 please post your exact code without editing so we can check