# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation Kendo ListView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have this kendo listview that I want to use in my Kendo Window

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo()
                     .Window()
                     .Name("WindowDocs")
                     .Title("Add Documente")
                     .Visible(false)
                     .Modal(true)
                     .Draggable(true)
                     .Width(440)
                     .Height(300)
                     //.LoadContentFrom("GetDocs","Controller")
                     .Content(@<text>
                        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                          .Name("Document")
                           .Multiple(false)
                           .Async(a => a
                        .Save("UploadDocs", "Controller"))
                         .Events(e => e.Complete("saveDocs"))
                        )
    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<DocViewModel>(@Model)
     .Name("listView")

    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("template")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDoc", "Controller"))
        )
    )    

    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                          .Name("SubmitBtn")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit" })
                          .Content("Save")
                        .Events(ev => ev.Click("saveDocuments")

                        ))
       </text>))
</div>
```

But I get this error when I try to write operations for my ListView

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type

Does someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Not exactly the same but the answer still applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754042/cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operat

Comment: You'll need to strongly type the response of your lambda expression

Comment: @twoleggedhorse Can you give me an example for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @(Html.Kendo().ListView<Entity.Models.DocViewModel>()
     .Name("listView")
            .TagName("div")
            .ClientTemplateId("DocumentList")

    )
```

Nevermind, I had a syntax error.